# Directive = and @ combo

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have my directive used at differennt pages :-

For example(prototype) :-

```
<my-directive title="{{title}}"></my-directive>
```

in this case I can get value in scope

```
scope:{
 title:"="
}
```

But in some places the data is static with same directive defination:-

```
<my-directive title="Hello"></my-directive>
```

Now same directive is not getting title :-(

Is there a way I can use "=" even with normal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use quotes `''` as,

```
<my-directive title="'Hello'"></my-directive>
```

Comment: You got it dear thanks :).I am stupid how can i forgot this :D

Comment: its glad to help u :)